# How to put a conditional breakpoint to test if a CString variable is empty

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

So I have this simple code snippet:

```
CString str;
..................
if ( str.IsEmpty() )
   str = spRelease->GetID();
```

I want to put a conditional breakpoint on the last line to test if str is empty.
I tried this first:

```
str == ""
```

But I get this:

```
Error overloaded operator not found
```

Then this:

```
str.isEmpty() == 0
```

And get this:

```
Symbol isEMpty() not found
```

Any idee how this could be done ? Any workaround ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just put a normal breakpoint on the last line? You already know str is empty. If you want to double check whether your string is empty, I would use an ASSERT instead.

If you really have to check your string, you have to check `m_pszData` in your CString, so your condition looks like this:

```
str.m_pszData[0] == '\0'
```

Comment: I need to test if after the initialization is empty, only then I want to debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 6 you have the operation IsEmpty(), note that the first 'I' is uppercase. You also have the Compare() operation. Which version of VS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

One pattern that I've seen for things like this is to add a bit of code like this:

```
if (some_condition) {
   int breakpoint=rand();
}
```

This generates a warning about `breakpoint` being initialized but not used so it is easy to remember to take it back out.  This also allows you test any condition you want, including invoking functions or anything else, without having to worry about restructions of the debugger.  This also avoids the limit on the number of conditional breakpoints you can have that some debuggers have.

The obvious downsides are that you can't add one during a debug session, recompiling, remembering to take them out, etc.